# 3D sprites, writing correct depth buffer information

Tags: opengl-es, opentk

I am writing a particle engine for iOS using Monotouch and openTK. My approach is to project the coordinate of each particle, and then write a correctly scaled textured rectangle at this screen location.

it works fine, but I have trouble calculating the correct depth value so that the sprite will correctly overdraw and be overdrawn by 3D objects in the scene.

This is the code I am using today:

```
//d=distance to projection plane
float d=(float)(1.0/(Math.Tan(MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(fovy/2f))));
Vector3 screenPos=Vector3.Transform(ref objPos,ref viewMatrix, out screenPos);
float depth=1-d/-screenPos.Z;
```

Then I am drawing a trianglestrip at the screen coordinate where I put the depth value calculated above as the z coordinate.

The results are almost correct, but not quite. I guess I need to take the near and far clipping planes into account somehow (near is 1 and far is 10000 in my case), but I am not sure how. I tried various ways and algorithms without getting accurate results.

I'd appreciate some help on this one.

Comment: That seems like an odd way of going about things; ES 1.1 comes with the point sprite extension built in and in ES 2.0 you'd be doing relevant things in the vertex shader — is there a reason you're doing this transform on the CPU?

Comment: I'm a beginner at OpenGl so pardon me if I do it in an awkward way. :) But from my understanding, if I use the regular pipeline then I would need to build a rotation matrix per particle to ensure it always faces the camera. This gives an overhead I'd like to avoid, and I also do not want to see any perspective effects like such a camera facing billboard would give if it is passing you close while facing you. I am using ES 2.0.

Comment: No, no need to think in terms of geometry, you can just supply the location of the point and have OpenGL put a 2d shape on that point. You'd achieve that via the point sprite extension in ES 1.1 but in 2.0 you can use the built-in output `gl_PointSize` in your vertex shader and the built-in input `gl_PointCoord` in your fragment shader. I've edited my answer to say pretty much that at more length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to do is take your source position and pass it through modelview and projection or whatever you've got set up instead if you're not using the fixed pipeline. Supposing you've used one of the standard calls to set up the stack, such as [glFrustum](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glFrustum.xml), and otherwise left things at identity then you can get the relevant formula directly from the man page. So reading directly from that you'd transform as:

```
z_clip = -( (far + near) / (far - near) ) * z_eye - ( (2 * far * near) / (far - near) )
w_clip = -z
```

Then, finally:

```
z_device = z_clip / w_clip;
```

EDIT: as you're working in ES 2.0, you can actually avoid the issue entirely. Supply your geometry for rendering as GL_POINTS and perform a normal transform in your vertex shader but set `gl_PointSize` to be the size in pixels that you want that point to be.

In your fragment shader you can then read `gl_PointCoord` to get a texture coordinate for each fragment that's part of your point, allowing you to draw a point sprite if you don't want just a single colour.

Comment: That looks like a much more efficient way, I was not aware you can texture a point like this using a shader in opengl. :) However I have one more requirement I did not mention before. I need to be able to rotate the textured particle around its center point. Is this possible using this approach? And can particles using points be non square?

Comment: You could do the rotation within the fragment shader if you're fine with dependant texture reads (they're generally to be avoided where possible but in this case you'd multiple your geometry costs by four to avoid them so neither is the obviously better solution), and definitely achieve a circle in there. But I think I'm right to say that you're always going to get an axis-aligned square with viewport-aligned texture coordinate mapping from GL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Due to the limitations with point sprites (must be round and does not support texture atlas animations), I cannot use it this technique now, but its useful to know for later. I will stick with the original approach I think, as traditional billboarding has it's own issues as mentioned above, unless there is some other clever way to do it in opengl which I missed..? :)

Comment: No, you're thinking of the point sprite extension from ES 1.1. In 2.0 you get the coordinate relative to the whole shape as input and do whatever transform you want to get to output. So shrink the co-ordinate and offset it to work with an atlas, for example. And I think I'm right to say you'll get a square unless you shape it yourself.